# “Add comment” button should not fail review audit

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing [first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts), I was shown [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4852703).  I thought it was a good question, and I wanted to ask what the term **odr-used** means, so I pressed <kbd>add comment</kbd>.

For daring to taint a good question with my filthy comment, I was struck down:
[image: audit fail]

Now I cannot make any more reviews.

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4852703.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

Review audits should not fail due to the <kbd>add comment</kbd> button.